# What's the mistake in the following query?

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access

I have the following query:

```
strsql = """SELECT referencia, concepto, sfamilia, pvp, puc FROM almacen2 WHERE concepto like '*YATEKOMO*'"""
```

I use this sentence in python with the Access Driver.

When I execute this in my code:

```
strsql = """SELECT referencia, concepto, sfamilia, pvp, puc FROM almacen2"""
```

I get a lot of results.

And when I try to execute the query with the tag LIKE in Access directly, I get 8 results.

What's my mistake so I get results out of my code and not in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%` instead of `*`.

Or do RegEx with `concepto ~ 'YATEKOMO'`

---

Oops, I can see that this is about ACCESS. My answer fits more to PostgreSQL.